# how to simplify this Boolean expression to 3 literals?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

How do I simplify this to 3 literals/letters?

= LM'+LN+N'B

How would you simplify this boolean expression? I don't know which boolean laws I need to use. I tried but I couldn't get it down to 3 literals only 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also not been able to reduce your expression to three literals.

The Karnaugh map:

```
            BL
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
MN    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

From looking at the map, you can see that three terms are needed to cover the nine minterms (depicted by "1") in the map. Each of the terms has two literals and covers four minterms. A term with just one literal would cover eight minterms.

Comment: ya, you're right I brought it up with the professor and he said there was an error in the question and made the changes to the question.